# Bootstrap modal disappearing in ASP MVC 5, and not from double loading bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm toggling a model from Javascript, but it disappears immediately. I'm not loading bootstrap-modal (which is one of the problems people have). Also, I tried eliminating bootstrap.min.js, and that didn't fix it either. I tried `.modal()`, `.modal('show')` and `.modal('toggle')`. Also, this was a VisualStudio initialized MVC project, so I didn't put in place all the jquery and bootstrap loads.

**EDIT**
Another complexity here is that I only want the modal to pop up if the submission is successful. I'm having an idea: Let the form submit and the controller redirect to another page on successful submission -- the inventory listing. From the "Create" controller, build a viewbag that can tell the inventory listing page whether or not the addition was successful. Then put the modal on the inventory listing page. Not really a solution to the problem -- a total workaround.

**Modal**

```
<div id="confirmAddedToInventoryModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Item Added to Inventory</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#create-form').on('submit', function () { $('#confirmAddedToInventoryModal').modal('toggle') });
    })
</script>
```

**New javascript attempt**

```
    $(function () {
        $('#create-button').on('click', function () {
            $('#confirmAddedToInventoryModal').modal('toggle');
        });

        $('#confirmAddedToInventoryModal').modal().hide(function () {
            $('create-form').submit();
        });
    });
```

Modal opens on page load, not just button click.

Comment: Are you trying to control submission of the form, or simply display a confirmation that some action completed successfully?

Comment: Confirm that the action completed successfully. I realized that one basic problem here is that the controller redirects to another page, not back to the page with the form.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're trying to handle a submit event, you need to cancel that event. Otherwise, the page is going to continue submitting. Bootstrap modals are not blocking, unlike native alerts.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Add the 'e' parameter, so that we can capture the event
        $('#create-form').on('submit', function (e) {
            // prevent the event
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#confirmAddedToInventoryModal').modal('toggle');
        });
    })
</script>
```

The drawback to this is that you will need to then manually submit the form after your "confirm" dialog has been processed.

Comment: That makes sense! So, I want the form to actually submit. Do I then need to bind the form submitting to the modal close event?

Comment: @abalter Yes and no. You're handling the event correctly already, you just need a way to either retrigger the submit event, or you would use one of the $.ajax methods to submit the contents of the form through JavaScript.

Comment: @abalter One option is to not use a submit button, but a button with `type="button"` (which doesn't trigger a submit event) as the "Submit" button in your form. That wouldn't handle the form being submitted through other means, though.

Comment: I implemented the second suggestion, however I ran into a problem. I trigger the modal to the button, and then the form submission to the `.hide` event. For some reason, the modal shows up as soon as the page load, which doesn't make any sense (code above). But there is another issue that I didn't think of. I only want the modal to come up if *the submission is successful*. This makes me think that I should use Ajax. However, the controller post method redirects to another page after updating the database with the form data. This all leaves me in a quandary.

Comment: What I'm trying to do may be impossible -- check if the form submitted properly without handing over control to the controller. Although, it would be enough to know that the form is validated. But I'm doing that through model annotations, so I don't know how to intercept it.

Comment: I see - thanks for the edit. I'm still running into the problem I described above.

Comment: Would a normal POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern work, with just the addition of a confirmation message on the "list" view I'm assuming you redirect to? You basically just want to add something to say "Yes, the insert/update DID in fact work" on the list page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81761/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-abalter).

Answer (score 0):

It was happen to me too, I just erase the script link on the layout 
~/Scripts/bootstrap.js
and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

change the button tag to an anchor tag:

```
 <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
```